# Computing correlation by groups in R with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I am new here and new to R.
I have a question and am hoping that maybe someone can help me out.
This is a snapshot of the dataset that I am working with

```
head(Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads)  
  date       average_correlation                            Reference_Entity
1 2009-02-12           0.4631034            EDP - Energias de Portugal, S.A.
2 2009-02-12           0.4631034 International Business Machines Corporation
3 2009-02-12           0.4631034                          Domtar Corporation
4 2009-02-12           0.4631034                               MetLife, Inc.
5 2009-02-12           0.4631034                            Caterpillar Inc.
6 2009-02-12           0.4631034                            GKN HOLDINGS PLC
  Days_Left_Until_Clearing
1                     -333
2                     -431
3                    -2349
4                     -788
5                     -368
6                    -1845
```

So, I've got columns rows: date - average correlation - reference entity - days left until clearing.

In total I have 1.076.435 entries: the date is ranging from 12.02.2009 to 04.06.2018 and it is repeated in its column a total of 461 times because we have 461 reference entities who each have a certain amount of days left until they have to be cleared. The average correlation that is already in the dataset is the average of the daily correlations of fourteen banks which were a part of my sample for this analysis.

Now, what I have to do is calculate the average correlation for all of the correlations that are listed as having for example 300 days left until clearing. And then the average correlation for all of the correlations that have 299 days left until clearing and so on and so forth. I have been told that the package `ddply` is the one to work with for this, but as I am a newbie to all of this, I haven't been able to get it to work.

I have tried:

```
Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads_Average_Correlation <- ddply(Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads$date, 
  Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads$average_correlation, 
  Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads$Days_Left_Until_Clearing, "date", cor)
```

because I wanted to create a new dataset with the rows "date" "average correlation" and clearly I have made some kind of mistake because I've been receiving error messages.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you are trying to do? Are you trying to take the `average_correlation` and calculate an average for `days_left_until_clearing = -300`, then `days_left_until_clearing = -299` etc. or `days_left_until_clearing <= -300`, then `days_left_until_clearing <= -299` etc.?

Comment: So this is the what the situation looks like: I have 461 reference entities and they each have different “days left until clearing” from 12.02.2009-04.06.2018 and I have to calculate the average correlation from ALL of the average correlations that already exist in the dataset that have the same amount of days left until clearing - say I have 3 average calculations that are matched to “400 days left until clearing” - I then have to calculate the average of those 3 calculations... but this I have to do for every single “days left until clearing” - was I able to properly explain myself?

Comment: Why is `avg_correlation` always 0.4631034 in the sample?  On the assumption that you have varying values in your sample, I'd suggest `library(dplyr); avg_cor_by_day = Clearing_Dates_CDS_Spreads %>% group_by(Days_Left_Until_Clearing) %>% summarize(avg_cor = mean(avg_correlation))`

Comment: The reason it is the same is that for the first 461 rows it's always the same day (12.02.2008) since we have 461 reference entities that all have a certain amount of days left until clearing, so for all of 12.02.2008, there is the same average correlation - for the 13.02.2008, there is another average correlation which is then again repeated for another 461 rows and this goes on until we reach the 04.06.2018. - I will try your code in a minute and will get back to you ASAP!

Comment: @JonSpring Oh wow! It worked! I ended up with a new dataframe with two rows, one with "Days_Left_Until_Clearing" and the other with "Average_Correlation" - I do have a question though: I want to understand the code and what exactly it is saying - what does the "%>%" mean in the code?

Comment: In `dplyr`, that's the "pipe" symbol that sends the output of one step into the first input of the next step. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/